# Glide/Picasso не загружают изображение

Tags: java, android, kotlin, picasso, glide

Попытался загрузить изображение через Picasso - не получилось, через Glide - тоже не получилось.

Пример кода на Picasso и Glide:

```
    val image = row.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.image)

    Glide.with(contextMain).load("ссылка на изображение с протоколом http").into(image);

    Picasso.get().load("ссылка на изображение с протоколом http").into(image);
```

Где переменная `image` - `ImageView`, а `contextMain` - контекст с `MainActivity`

Вот файл Манифеста

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.IMDBMovieFinder"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"> 
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Сайт блокирует ссылки в вопросах. Вот ссылка, с которой я беру изображение:  http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png

Comment: В логах должно выводится, что не так